# What's the difference between Remove and Exclude when refactoring with PyCharm?

Tags: refactoring, pycharm

The [official PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/refactoring-source-code.html?origin=old_help) explain `Exclude` when it comes to refactoring:  One can, say, rename something with refactoring (Shift+F6), causing the Find window to pop up with a Preview.  Within, it shows files which will be updated as a result of the refactor.  One can right-click on a file or folder in this Preview and choose `Remove` or `Exclude`.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Final effect is the same - entry which was `Removed` or `Excluded` won't be refactored, the difference is in presentation. After selecting `Exclude` you keep entry in the `Refactoring Preview`, but `Remove` deletes it from that window.

I think that `Remove` could be useful when you deal with quite large refactoring and marking everything as excluded could lead to unreadable mess.

Keep in mind, that **remove action can't be undone** - you have to start new refactoring...